# Can't get node-debug to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector, node-debugger

This feels really silly, but I can't get node inspector / `node-debug` to work.

The instructions say to do npm install then to run `node-debug web.js`. So I did that. Now I have a lovely browser window open showing me my code with breakpoints... and no idea which url to use to actually access the code.

The inspector is at `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858` and the terminal says:

```
> node-debug web.js
debugger listening on port 5858
Node Inspector is now available from http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
Debugging `web.js`
```

...

I've tried hitting up `localhost:5000` (which is my `express.js` port) but that either fails if I don't have a separate `node web.js` instance running, or it succeeds if I have the other one running but doesn't trip any of the breakpoints in the inspector.

When I go to `http://localhost:5858/`, I get:

> Remote debugging session already active

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/`, I get:

> Cannot GET /

(the `/` path totally works on my server in general.)

Comment: By default ```node-debug``` starts app in ```--debug-brk``` mode. This stops your app at first line (express not started). You can use ```node-debug --no-debug-brk``` see the ```node-debug --h``` for more info

Comment: Oh! I think that's the real answer. If you add it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `node-debug` starts app in `--debug-brk` mode. 
This stops your app at first line (express not started).

You can use `node-debug --no-debug-brk` see the `node-debug --h` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Agh. Okay, looked at some more questions before I got this posted. Looks like the problem was just that I wasn't running the original instance in debug mode. Nobody had told me I had to, so I just didn't know otherwise!

What's working for me now:

```
> node debug web
```

then in a different terminal

```
> node-debug web.js
```

Comment: Are you mean ```node --debug web```?

Comment: In any case this is a bad solution. You start one instance of express server and then other for debugging...